# Rudeness in the workpace

Tags: communication, resignation, manager, exit-interview

I am a junior developer and my boss is quite rude to me. I am giving two examples,

1. I ask too many questions (I accept this fact but all of my questions are domain specific and could not be found on internet.) to learn the job good. One time after I asked something, he answered it very superficial and I did not understand and said: sorry, I did not understand and he said loudly: damn it (the German version of Damn it is quite rude)
2. The system did not start and I told him that the system could not be started and he completed my sentence "or you are not talented"

After these rude behaviours, I do not ask any new questions because I know myself, if he says something like that one more time, my reaction will be very hard, which I do not want.

I do not want to work with him anymore and it means also, I cannot work in the company because he is very experienced in his field. However, what I want is that I do not want to hide this rudeness against a junior developer to protect the person after me.

Before me, there was another developer, who left the company because of him but he did not say anything about his behaviours and I do not want to leave like him.

In which way should I express these to the "big boss" to make him realize that people are leaving the company because of him before I resign?

Comment: Have you brought this up with your chef yet? It's likely you won't be taken very seriously unless you've at least tried to resolve it with him first.

Comment: I think you will find good advice in this similar question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59095/senior-architect-lashing-out-when-junior-developer-asks-questions-what-to-do

Comment: @Erik I think it is a universal fact that he should not talk to anybody like that. He knows his mistakes and after he says something like that he tries to make it good by making mistakes but too late.

Comment: @KateGregory I have read your answer. It is very helpful but I do not want to continue in this company under these circumstances and I believe I cannot change his personality. I just want to show him that he is an asshole in a polite way.

Comment: @AdInfinitum what's the point to showing him is an asshole in a polite way, if you claim he already knows he is one AND it doesn't change anything since you'll leave either way? What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe it is just your descriptions, but from what you say here you sound overly sensitive to me. While I don't like the behavior of your boss in the two examples, please keep in mind bosses are humans too (i.e. they can be wrong). Your first example ("damn it" translates to "Verdammt noch mal", which is not very rude imho) is harmless. The second one is worse, but if it is an isolated incident I would give your boss the benefit of the doubt. Maybe he had a bad day or it was a poor attempt of humor.

Comment: @Erik I editted my answer, please read the paragraf before the last paragraf. It answers your question.

Comment: @DavidK I editted my answer. Please review it again. It is not the duplicate of the given link.

Comment: @dirkk bosses are humans too, so are we. You are right. You said "Verdammt noch mal" is not very rude. What would happen, if I say the same to him? He works for the company more than I work does not give him the right to behave the people like that.

Comment: @AdInfinitum We cannot tell what would happen if *you* said "verdammt noch mal". But in terms of developer language, "verdammt noch mal" is not very rude. Developers curse all the time. Finding a boss who's not cursing will probably mean you need to find a shop where you are the only developer.

Comment: @nvoigt I cannot understand how did all people accept the rudeness so easily. He can curse at code, system, wall but not at another person, especially a person, who tries to make his job better.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I explained the reason in my question like that "Before me, there was another developer, who left the company because of him but he did not say anything about his behaviours and I do not want to leave like him." . I do not think that it is a waste of time if I protect the person after me.

Comment: @AdInfinitum I have to agree with nvoigt.  An ancient joke in IT is that the one language understood by all programmers is profanity.  Snark and insult are also common.  You need a tough, thick skin in this business.

Comment: @RichardU Everybody has a different personality. I am a serious man, who does not make joke or insult anybody. If somebody does not want to work with me, he can tell me politely and I would take it very professionally and leave the company with good relations but insults are not my thing.

Comment: @AdInfinitum I had this same conversation with a young man at a previous employer.  You're walking into a culture that has a certain way of doing things.  You need to learn to adapt because the culture is not going to adapt to you

Comment: Please **READ** the question before deciding it's a dupe.This question may be a duplicate, but not of the question that is being cited.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Is German your mother tongue? It is for me (and also for nvoigt I would guess) and we both told you it is not very rude. I still don't see this as rude and I don't think anyone I know would consider this rude. If it is not your native language, maybe it is more a language/cultural issue than a rudeness issue? In General, German culture is quite blunt which many other cultures consider quite rude.

Comment: @dirkk No, I am not a native speaker. Under the question of nvoigt, I have given an example. He made it the same with the mouse. I may combine the physical behaviour with what he said and came to a conclusion like that.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Again, as nvoigt, I would also say this is either harmless or I wouldn't get the behavior. You came here for advice and although it appears to not be the answer you are looking for, now multiple people here told you they do not consider it rude at all (not even borderline, to be honest). Maybe you could also ask some native co-workers of you, who also know your boss if they consider his behavior as rude. I am almost certain they don't. This is a language/culture issue and it will not be any different in your next job if you do not address the underlying issue.

Comment: Sounds to me like the manager expected a certain level of skill that, given the number of questions you ask combined with an inability to solve issues the manager believes you should be able to solve, does not appear to be there.  As this is not a good fit for you it's time to leave.

Comment: @dirkk No, sorry, I believe of course what you and nvoigt said. I only said how I interpreted his behaviour. It is possibly a cultural issue like what you said. In my culture, it is very impolite to say something like that in a work environment. I will get used to it.

Comment: Vote to re-open. I do not think this question is a dup. In the linked question, the OP is the only expert in a certain area in the company. In this question, the OP is a junior developer. How could we say this is a duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure it's actually *rude*.

Developers that are good and have fun working tease and ridicule each other all the time.

Assuming I'd say something like

> When I press F5 to compile, Visual Studio says "internal compiler error".

The other colleagues around the table are guaranteed to say something like:

> Man, you *really* suck at compiling.
>
> I will go ask $boss if we can hire someone who has better F5-pressing-skills than you.
>
> You cannot get *anything* done, can you?
>
> Maybe you should let somebody else press F5, you just don't have what it takes.

All four will grin. Taken literally, it's rude. It's obvious that it's not meant to be. It's developer humor.

So 1) make sure it's meant to be rude, 2) make sure you don't make mistakes ("I ask too many questions").

If you *really* intent to waste your time to try to improve the company you leave, make sure you have a *list* of occurrences and quotes. A single "verdammt" after you admitted it was your fault, will not raise any eyebrows. So that guy did not keep cool when you made a mistake. *Once*. But he is still working for the company and you are not. You need a really long list of documented behaviors for anybody to believe you.

Comment: Ok. I change your example a little bit. You pressed F5 to compile and I said something like "You cannot get anything done, can you?" and then, I took the keyboard from you and click on the F5 hardly by shaking my head. Would you take it as a joke?

Comment: @AdInfinitum I would not get it. But your second example ("Does not start", "or you are not talented enough to start it") would absolutely be a direct quotation from our daily fun making.

Comment: The second one could be a "bad" humor. However, because of the first "insult", I take everything serious what he makes/says. Maybe, because of this reason, I did not get the second one.

Comment: @AdInfinitum I would pay careful attention to what nvoigt is saying.  This is the environment.  It's not going to change and you are going to find it literally everywhere.

Comment: I think this is a great answer with some quick caveats: Yes, you should learn and not get offended by the culture around you (lord, some of the things I've heard and said that would have curled HR's toes...) but if you're uncomfortable about it, you do need to approach them and let them know that it's damaging your ability to produce. Most people with sense will understand this.

Comment: @nvoigt - what you are describing is sort of sarcasm between the colleagues, which is quite common in some environments and somehow shows appreciation towards the colleagues (you wouldn't say those if it was really true, would you?). What the OP is describing is more of the boss showing off with his power over a junior developer. Very unprofessional in my opinion.

Comment: @Mike You are right about the sarcasm. I was not there so I cannot tell if it's the case with the OP. That's why I started with "Make sure, that..." Only the OP can answer that for himself, because written down, it's all the same.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have already made your decision to resign.

**Simply resign in a professional way and stay on good terms with your employer. 
 Don't bring this up.**

It may be satisfying to voice frustrations that you have held for a long time, but it won't help anything for you.  It would be much better to stay on good terms with your employer (and your boss specifically), as you will probably need a reference in the future.

It's unlikely that speaking up to higher management will do anything to improve the situation for future junior employees.  The situation would be your word against the manager's, and you are a junior employee who is quitting.  It seems unlikely that they will weight your word heavily.

Comment: I understand and it is very logical but at the end of day, if we hide our frustrations For the sake of professionalism, would it not harm to our psychology?

Comment: @AdInfinitum expressing your feelings is good.  But it doesn't have to be to your boss...

Comment: @dan1111 is saying "go to the bar, have a drink and mutter lovely select phrases about the bossman into your cup" ^_^ Or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you know someone left before you because of this person's behavior is something that I'd assume management knows about and may not do anything because this person who is rude may be a higher-up or executive.  You may wish to state in your exit interview, but it will most likely be for your own sense of closure and not that the company is going to do anything further about this. If you find you cannot work with this person and they are crucial to helping you do your job, you can either ignore the comments, ask for a private 10 minute meet with them to find out how to work better with this person and state you don't have time for nasty remarks, you are here to help them and without their help you can't get your work done, or find another job, stay polite keep your head down, and depending on where you live, give notice or quit when you are ready.  When you do hand in your resignation notice, be prepared to be escorted out, so do this when you have your ducks in a row.